# Insert spaces based on words/dictionary

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to take phrases with no spaces in (such as a trending topic on twitter) and put spaces in where appropriate based on the words in the phrase. Presumably some sort of comparison with a dictionary would work?

For example: I'd have a function that took the phrase 'septemberwish' (current trending on twitter) and it would return 'september wish'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be tricky. You'll easily get ambiguous words amalgamations, where several separations result in valid words.

That said, you can use a spell checker. See the [pspell](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/book.pspell.php) extension.

An algorithm can just separate the word in different points until it yields two valid words. Example:

```
septem berwish    (split at floor(length/2); both invalid)
septemb erwish    (split at floor(length/2)+1; both invalid)
septe mberwish    (split at floor(length/2)-1; both invalid)
septembe rwish    (split at floor(length/2)+2; both invalid)
sept emberwish    (split at floor(length/2)-2; first valid, second invalid)
september wish    (split at floor(length/2)+3; both valid; stop)
```

For more than two words, another approach is needed. One possibility is to remove characters from the end until you have a valid word, and then do the same for rest that didn't get matched:

```
septemberwishtwo (invalid)
septemberwishtw  (invalid)
...
september        (valid; got the first)
wishtwo          (invalid)
...
wish             (valid; got the second)
two              (valid; got the third)
```

Comment: This would work for a 2 word phrase, but harder to implement for any phrases longer than 2 words? It could get very complicated very quickly!

Comment: Isn't starting in the middle only helpful if you're assuming it's two words. I don't know anything about twitter, but couldn't it just as easily be one word or four?

Comment: +1 for pspell, though I like the idea of parsing from the beginning, as @Piskvor suggests.

Comment: @Finn OK, I added another algorithm.

Comment: @Artefacto: well, I'll parse Pen Island correctly, and you'll parse the *hyphen site* right. Wonder if there is a way to combine the backward and forward approaches.

Comment: @Piskvor Well, using the two approaches wouldn't be enough. We'd needy options that captured neither the smallest nor the longest match. As to what is correct when there are multiple possibilities, we'd need probabilistic approaches -- there's a whole field dedicated to that.

Answer (score 1):

In the most naive implementation, start adding letters from the start of the string, and compare with a dictionary for a given length: e.g.

```
s // no match
se // no match
sep // no match
...
september // match! add space, add to output
// continue where we left off
w // no match
wi // no match
wis // no match
wish // match! add space, add to output
end of string, terminate
```

The tricky bit: there could be strings that could be parsed into various phrases ([the-site-that-shall-not-be-named](http://www.expert-sex-change.com/), for one). Actually, your example is one (although one word is uncommon):

[sept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sept)[ember](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ember)[wish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wish) vs [september](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September)[wish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wish)

I guess you could try with a smaller dictionary of common words first, or longest words first; or give less commonly used words a lower weight.

Comment: This is what I thought, too, but it seems you have to go back and start all over when it's a single word starting with 'a', 'the', etc.

Comment: @grossvogel: Some bactracking might be in order; although in this particular case, I'd say Twitter is conveniently filtering such words for us (otherwise "the" would be *the* trend of all time (pardon the pun)).